# $A^tA-AA^t$ in Mathematical Physics

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, intuition, mathematical-physics, geometric-interpretation

In very different contexts of mathematical physics (rigid body mechanics, fluidodynamics, general relativity, quantum field theory,...) I have come across the following expression:
$$
A^tA-AA^t,
$$

where $A$ is a square matrix and $A^t$ its transpose, or the vector analogue:
$$
vv^t-\Bbb{1}v^tv,
$$
where $\Bbb{1}$ is the identity and $v$ is a vector (or also the differential operator $\nabla$).

What do the quantities above really measure? Is there an intuitive, geometric or algebraic meaning? Any explanation which works only in one context (say, fluidodynamics) would be also welcome.

Thanks!

**Addendum**: Thanks to Autolatry's answer, here is an example of what I mean by "intuitive meaning": The first term alone, namely $A^tA$, has the significance of a *magnitude* (at least in the Euclidean case). It gives the metric tensor for embedded submanifolds, it gives the length of a vector, its determinant gives the volume form...
I'm asking if the difference of the two terms above also has a geometrical meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a perfectly suitable description of what $AA^{T}$ and $A^{T}A$ can represent (certianly out of my comfort zone with regards fluid dynamics)other that to say that for some special types of [groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_group) the transpose matrix is actually the inverse, the rotation matrices have this property.So geometrically the rotation matrices preserve length.

A more rigorous geometric interpretation is to consider a parameterization of a $k$-manifold $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\gamma: \mathbb{R}^{k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

The Jacobian $J=[D\gamma]$ is such that $J^{T}J$ is the metric induced on $M$ by the embedding in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Yes! In particular, $A^tA$ has a metric significance, it gives the length (for vectors), or metric tensors, or first fundamental forms. I'm asking exactly what the *difference* measures, though. Anyway your answer suggested me an edit, so thank you!